# C# Winforms how to get details of CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

**Goal**

I am aiming to simply to do the following:

- Get details of `CheckedListBox`.
- The Title of the `CheckedListBox` record.
- The `boolean` value of the record. In other words, if the record is checked or not checked.

I need to store the information into a Dictionary.

**Example**

[image]

Using hardcoded values just as an example, it'll be something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, bool> dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

dict.Add("No", true);
dict.Add("Product Name", false);
dict.Add("Sign", true);
dict.Add("Month", true);
```

**What I have tried to get details from `CheckedListBox`:**

```
Dictionary<string, bool> dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

foreach(CheckedListBox box in checkedListBox1.Items)
{
    dict.Add(box.Items, box.GetItemChecked);
}
```

I cannot find any correct properties when using intellisense, I was hoping to get the title of each record and the check state of each record.

Comment: Hunting around Intellisense is probably not the best way to figure things out. Go to the source (MSDN): [How to: Determine Checked Items in the Windows Forms CheckedListBox Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-determine-checked-items-in-the-windows-forms-checkedlistbox-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [`CheckedListBox.Items`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.items) returns an instance of [`CheckedListBox.ObjectCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.objectcollection), so your `foreach` isn't quite right. I imagine it might look something like this instead...

```
foreach (object item in checkedListBox1.Items)
```

But, since you want to know whether each item is checked or not, you'd probably be better off with a `for` loop to loop through the items instead. You'll need to use [`CheckedListBox.GetItemChecked(int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemchecked) to determine if an item is checked or not. That function takes the index of the item you want to check.

Then you can use that index and `CheckedListBox.Items` to get the text of each individual item. You can call `ToString` to get the text of the item, assuming that the item isn't `null`.

Putting it all together might look something like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    dict.Add(checkedListBox1.Items[i].ToString(), checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i));
}
```